# Angular appending is fast but destroying is slow(1 second)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made link between html lists and fabricjs objects list.
This is html code

```
<div ng-repeat = "object in objects">
   {{objects.length.toString()}}
   {{object.name}}
</div>
```

This is angular code.

```
$rootScope.$watch(
  function(scope){
   return canvas.fabric._objects;
  },
  function(newValue, oldValue){
   $timeout(function(){
     $rootScope.$broadcast('_object:changed');
  }
});

$rootScope.$on('_object:changed', function(){
  $scope.objects = canvas.fabric._objects;
});
```

If I add object to fabric it is shown immediately in html list via angular but if I delete one or all, it is refreshed after a second.
Deleting code implementation

```
canvas.fabric._objects.length = 0;
```

Is there anyone met this kind of issue? How can I make this refresh within 0.01 second?

UPDATE: I found that refreshing is doing very fast but deleted one is hidden after 1 second.

**RESULT: If I delete "book" from the list(["home","book","pen"])**

```
   init  :3home,3book,3pen  
   0.01s :2home,3book,2pen  
   1s:    2home,2pen
```

at 0.01s
 2 is list length.
 3book exist until next 1 second even if the angular is refreshed and the object list value is changed.

Comment: Hey, I deleted my answer because it wasn't helpful. I'll post another one if something comes to mind

Comment: Thanks really I updated angular to 1.6.5 and the same result happened.

Comment: Do you think deleting time (.length = 0) is slow(1s)?

Comment: I'm not sure, I need to research this. I'll update you if I find anything. Hope someone else could help you.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, I only now see that you have a `$timeout` with missing `)` in you example (I think) - So I just want to be sure: Try  to remove it from the `function(newValue, oldValue){ ... }`  ==> `function(newValue, oldValue){ $rootScope.$broadcast('_object:changed'); }, true)`

Comment: Hey again, try changing `{{objects.length.toString()}}` to `{{ objects.length }}` - Perhaps [this exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)  is the reason for the delayed refresh of the view. Let me know if this, or my previous comment changed anything

Comment: Please see this line  0.01s :2home,3book,2pen  it means refreshing is doing well but deleted one 3book is shown, I think it is ng animation problem, I don't know about ng animation and I am now digging into ng animation

Comment: Ah yes - This is probably the reason, I've seen this happen before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.
I just changed

```
canvas.fabric._objects.length = 0;
```

to

```
canvas.fabric._objects = [];
```

and just solved.